# How do I find the value of a partial sum without calculator?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometric-series

Without using a calculator, how do I find:

$$\sum_{k=0}^7 \left(\tfrac{2}{3}\right)^k $$

I know about the formula for the sum of a geometric series $\frac{a\cdot(1-r^n)}{(1-r)}$ but im not sure how to apply it. I feel as if you make a small series and try to formulate a equation out of it, such as:

$$ \left(\tfrac{2^0}{3^0}\right)+\left(\tfrac{2^1}{3^1}\right)...\left(\tfrac{2^7}{3^7}\right)$$

and pull out some value. I'm lost after that. Any help?

Comment: what you want isn't a series, instead, it is only a partial sum

Answer (score 2):

So that formula for the sum of geometric series was

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a r^i = a \frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$

Compare this to $$\sum_{i=0}^{7} (-2/3)^i$$ to identify what is a, r and n. Then plug those in.

Comment: ok i see now. it makes me feel bad when i miss something like this :(. but thank you for your time!